# Can Geordi see in the dark?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology

Does the VISOR afford Geordi this capability?

Answer (score 17):

Yes. In [TNG : The Masterpiece Society](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/213.txt) we learn that his VISOR...

> *...scans the electromagnetic spectrum between one hertz and one hundred
>   thousand terahertz, converts it all to usable frequencies and carries
>   the information directly to the brain.*

As such, Geordie's vision ranges from the deep radio band, through infra-red and well into the ultra-violet. That would easily allow him to see in the dark, even if the visible band was totally absent.

[image]

Comment: Note that [humans are transparent to quite a bit of light](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod4.html#c1).  Seeing wouldn't be what we think of it at all. While he may be able to detect waves in a given range, what is seen and not depends significantly on the material that the thing is made of.

Comment: I remember that line too, (as well as other references to Geordi being able to see "better" than the average human), and I've always wondered how he could process it all. If you could see radio waves, it's a wonder you could ever see anything else - there would just be light all around you at all times.

Comment: @Bachrach44, there was one episode where they piped the VISOR to the main viewscreen on the bridge, and Geordi was asked basically that question. He countered by asking how you can pick out a single voice from a crowded room. Paraphrasing, "You just get used to it."

Comment: @Bachrach44 - Also, his visor seems to favour infra-red and ultra-violet.

Comment: Also this: https://twitter.com/Axetradies/status/514138851262996480/photo/1